# How Differential Cryptanalysis of DES work?

Tags: des, chosen-plaintext-attack, differential-analysis

I have been studying the DC of DES. As a beginner, I completed the general structure of DES and began DC. I understand the idea of attack, how to find different characteristics for differential cryptanalysis of des-like systems?

Can someone explain them to me or point out a good explanation on the Internet?

Comment: [Hayes : A Tutorial on Linear and Differential Cryptanalysis](http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf)

Comment: @Ekin  Perhaps you could edit your question and detail what it is that you do not understand about the attacks.